# XSLT 2.0 string-join on a variable containing sorted nodes produces un-ordered output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a variable that contains a sequence of sorted nodes. When I use string-join to print out a list of the values, the order they are output is the order they are in the document, not the sorted order. Should this work, or am I stuck manually building the list with position() != last()?

### Template

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="SortedElements" as="element(Element)+">
    <xsl:perform-sort select="/Root/Element">
        <xsl:sort select="ElementNumber" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Iterating through variable: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$SortedElements">
        <xsl:value-of select="ElementNumber"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text> string-join: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($SortedElements/ElementNumber, ', ')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Example Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <Element>
        <ElementNumber>3</ElementNumber>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <ElementNumber>1</ElementNumber>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <ElementNumber>2</ElementNumber>
    </Element>
</Root>
```

### Output

```
Iterating through variable: 123 string-join: 3, 1, 2
```

Comment: There is another way if you get rid of the `as` attribute from variable declaration and create a temporary document. After that, `string-join($SortedElements/Element/ElementNumber, ', ')` will give the expected sorted order. It comes at a cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/ElementNumber` step in the string-join sorts in document order so use `string-join  (for $e in $SortedElements return $e/ElementNumber,',')` instead. Note that `xsl:value-of` takes a `separator` attribute, so instead of the `string-join` you can as well use `<xsl:value-of select="for $e in $SortedElements return $e/ElementNumber" separator=", "/>` or, if you switch to a `version="3.0"` stylesheet, `<xsl:value-of select="$sortedElements!ElementNumber" separator=", "/>`.